# Update WebView system component on KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, webview

does anyone know a way to update the WebView system component on KitKat. I'm running 4.4.4, I think people get updates in Google Play in Android 5.0 and above but I would like to update it on KitKat and keep using this OS as it runs smoother for me, I'm sure there is a way to do this, can anyone help? The Webview on KitKat has some horrible bugs..

Thanks!

Comment: Did you go to playstore and install it?

Comment: I tried, but it says that it is not supported for my device, I think that only works for Android 5.0 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 4.4 the webview component cannot be updated from the Play Store - it is fixed to version 30.0.0.0 (and 33.0.0.0 in 4.4.3). This was changed in Android 5.0:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

> In Android 5.0 (Lollipop), the WebView has moved to an APK so it can be updated seperately to the Android platform. To see what version of Chrome is currently used on a Lollipop device, simply go to Settings < Apps < Android System WebView and look at the version.